# How to find equations that define the image of an algebraic morphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

Suppose we have a map $f:\mathbb{P}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^m$ which is algebraic. What are the techniques to find the equations defining the image of f as a subvariety of $\mathbb{P}^m$?

For example in the case $f:\mathbb{P}^1\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^2$ , $[x,y]\mapsto [x^3,x^2y,y^3]$. I immediately see the equation $z_0^2z_2-z_1^3=0$ is satisfied on the image, and I suspect strongly that this is the only equation needed as in Euclidean coordinates we get a curve (cusp).

Comment: Many times you just find relations and prove that they are enough to describe the image. For example in your case, you don't need more equations since the image is going to be 1-dimensional and connected, and the equation you found is irreducible and lowers the dimension from 2 to 1 (you have a hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^2$).